# Creating my own struct for a packet that need to be sent from a server to a client with ethdr+iphdr+tcphdr+(char payload[100])

Tags: c, linux, google-chrome, sockets, tcp

I am working on sockets application so basically its a lower layer socket (Ethernet -- Like mmap to RX/TX ring). I like to create my own struct that represent my packet for sending. That struct is like this

```
  struct packet_to_send
      {
         struct ethhdr eth;
         struct iphdr ip;
         struct tcphdr tcp;
         char payload[1000];
      }
```

I like to know if I create object of above type then will it be a valid packet. means since I am creating Ethernet frame and including in it ip header and tcp header plus payload. I haven't tried that in working so I am curious that if I complete it will it work accordingly or what else I have to include if there is something is missing so all known browsers can connect to my server and fetch simple html. There is a three way handshake included which I know. Currently I have created the receiving packets thread. and this task is for sending packets thread.

I like if

1. the packet object from above struct can be understood by browsers like chrome,firefox, etc.
2. What struct alignment I have to include while creating above struct objects

(will keep array of them and reusing them for next packets to send -- possibly will be used/read/update in same thread but currently I don;t know for sure).

3. should the above struct object should be volatile (from point 2)

the above struct will be inside another struct that this like

```
    struct struct_connection{
        char source_ip[20];
        char dest_ip[20];
        struct struct_flag tcp_flag[3];
        int hand_shake_state;
        int my_port;
        int dest_port;
        void(*get_response_packet)(char packet_to_send *packet);
    
    };
```

I am excluding some detains from above struct since they are not relevant like last seq/ack_seq

Thanks for any help

Comment: No, you cannot. iphdr and tcphdr are variable sized (they can contain optional fields for the flags/options)

Comment: @wildplasser u mean iphdr and tcphdr sizes varies packet to packet.

Comment: @wildplasser I dont think so I am taking `malloc(sizeof(struct packet_to_send))` this way 0 will be 0 and 1 will be 1 in optional fields and flags.

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc791.html  (3.1) The size is encoded in version/IHL For TCP: GIYF

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc793.html for TCP The data-offset is the field you want. (the length is contained in the preceeding IP-pseudo-header)

Comment: `I am excluding some details from above struct since they are not relevant like last seq/ack_seq` Maybe they are important, after all. Think about fragments, window negotiation. These are not details.