# SegFault on memcpy and source and destination are defined and initialized

Tags: c, linux

I am getting segFault by copying to initialized pointer. this is relevant code

```
*pay = (char *)malloc(sizeof(t1) + 1020 /*1000=payload*/);
memset(*pay, 0, sizeof(t1) + 1020);
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *pay;
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

and I did

```
 memcpy(eth->h_dest, p->h_source, sizeof(eth->h_source));
```

But above line is causing a segfault. I am assigning `h_source` like this in other thread `memcpy((p)->h_source, received_packet_eth->h_source, sizeof(eth->h_source));`

`h_source` is inside struct `struct packets *p`
this is how its definition `struct packets *p` I am initializing and assigning in other thread, see above. So `struct packets *p` is not an uninitialized pointer. And I am sure it is being allocated when the segFault occurs.

```
unsigned char h_source[ETH_ALEN];   /* source ether addr    */
```

Thanks for any help

**Update** This is the full code of the function

```
void get_payload_to_send(struct packets *p, char **pay)
{
    printf("%s --->>> %s", p->ip_source, p->ip_dest);
    int t1;
    *pay = (char *)malloc(sizeof(t1) + 1020 /*1000=payload*/);
    memset(*pay, 0, sizeof(t1) + 1020);
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *pay;
    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));

    //if (p->h_proto == ntohs(p->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP)
    {
        if (p->syn == 1 && p->ack == 0 && p->fin == 0)
        {
            ///Ethernet
            //memcpy(eth->h_dest, p->h_source, sizeof(eth->h_source));

            eth->h_proto = htonl(ETH_P_IP);
            //memcpy(eth->h_source, p->h_dest, sizeof(eth->h_dest));
            ////IP

            // memcpy(ip->saddr, inet_addr(p->ip_dest), sizeof(ip->saddr));
            struct sockaddr_in s1, s2;
            s1.sin_family = AF_INET;
            s1.sin_port = htons(80);
            s1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(p->ip_source);

            s2.sin_family = AF_INET;
            s2.sin_port = htons(5009);
            s2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(p->ip_dest);
            //ip->saddr = s1.sin_addr.s_addr;
            sleep(2);
            ip->daddr = s2.sin_addr.s_addr;
            char c[20];
            memcpy(ip->saddr, inet_addr(p->ip_dest), sizeof(c) - 1);
            ip->ihl = 5;
            ip->version = 4;
            ip->tos = 0;
            ip->tot_len = sizeof(t1) + 1020;
            srand(1001);
            ip->id = htonl(rand());
            ip->frag_off = 0;
            ip->ttl = 225;
            ip->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            ip->check = 0;
            tcp->syn = 1;
            tcp->ack = 1;

            memcpy(ip->daddr, inet_addr(p->ip_source), sizeof(c) - 1);

            //ip->check = csum((unsigned short *)*pay, ip->tot_len);
        }
        else if (p->syn == 0 && p->ack == 1)
        {

        }
    }
    //printf("%saddr %s -->>", p->ip_source);
    //printf("daddr %s\n", p->ip_dest);
    //populate eth
}
```

This is the code from where the function call to above function is made

```
void *task_sender(void *args) {
    struct struct_super_struct *super = (struct struct_super_struct *)args;

    struct packets *p = super->p; //(struct packets *)args;
    printf("Sender\n");
    while (1)
    {
        //printf("got uppder loop SENDER\n");

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       
        while (nop == 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            //printf("finished waiting in SENDER\n");
        }
        int i = 0;

        printf("NOP is greater than 2 in SENDER %d\n");

        while (nop > 0)
        {
            // check_and_process_connection(super,(p+i));

            //if (p == NULL) break;
            if (strcmp("192.168.10.25", (p+i)->ip_dest) == 0 && (p+i)->syn == 1 && (p+i)->ack == 0)
            {
                //sleep(1);

                //printf("%s\n", (p+i)->ip_dest);
                //if (strcmp((p+i)->ip_dest, "192.168.10.25") == 0)
                {
                    char *pac;
                    struct packets *pt = (p+i);
                    get_payload_to_send((p+i), &pac);
                    struct sockaddr_in temp;
                    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)pac;
                    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *)(pac + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
                    struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *)(pac + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
                    temp.sin_addr.s_addr = ip->saddr;
                    char *source = inet_ntoa(temp.sin_addr);
                    struct sockaddr_in temp1;
                    temp1.sin_addr.s_addr = ip->daddr;
                    char *dest = inet_ntoa(temp1.sin_addr);
                    printf("%s >> %s \n", (p+i)->ip_source, (p+i)->ip_dest);
                    //if (strcmp("192.168.10.25",dest) == 0 && strcmp("192.168.10.25", source) == 0)
                    {
                        ///temp1.sin_addr.s_addr = ip->daddr;
                        printf("should be\n");
                        printf("frm %s to %s syc:%d ack:%d \n",
                               inet_ntoa(temp.sin_addr),
                               inet_ntoa(temp1.sin_addr),
                               tcp->syn, tcp->ack);
                    }
                    /*          
                    printf("__________________________________________________\n");
                    printf("lastop: %d\n", (p+i)->lastop);
                    printf("source: %s %d\n", (p+i)->ip_source, (p+i)->tcp_source);
                    printf("dest: %s %d\n", (p+i)->ip_dest, (p+i)->tcp_dest);
                    printf("syc: %d\n", (p+i)->syn);
                    printf("ack: %d\n", (p+i)->ack);
                    printf("seq: %d\n", (p+i)->seq);
                    printf("ack seq: %d\n", (p+i)->ack_seq);
                    (p+i)->lastop = 0;
                    printf("lastop: %d\n", (p+i)->lastop);
                    */
                }
                //printf("dest port: %d\n", (p+i)->tcp_dest);
            }
            //else { printf("source ip: %s\n", (p+i)->ip_source); printf("dest ip: %s\n", (p+i)->ip_dest); }
            //p++;
            nop--;
            i++;
            //printf("just processed packet SENDER\n");
        }
        //p = NULL;
    
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        nop = 0;
        int s = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

```
struct packets {
    int syn;
    char payload[1000];
//    pthread_mutex_t  mutex;
    int lastop;
    unsigned char h_dest[ETH_ALEN]; /* destination eth addr */
    unsigned char h_source[ETH_ALEN];   /* source ether addr    */
    __be16      h_proto;
    char ip_source[20];
    char ip_dest[20];
    int tcp_source;
    int tcp_dest;
    int seq;
    int ack_seq;

    int ack;
    int fin;
    int rst;
    int window;
    int nop;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *ip;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
}; // *p=NULL;
```

**Note** What I found debugging with gdb is that in `memcpy(eth->h_dest, p->h_source, sizeof(eth->h_source));` line `eth->hdest` is `NULL`

Comment: `*pay=(char *) malloc` don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: it matters, why. This is not why I am getting segFault. am I?

Comment: `pay` passed as argument `pointer to pointer` in side called function I with `*pay=(char *) malloc(sizeof(t1)+1020/*1000=payload*/);` initialized inside called function

Comment: @WeatherVane see my comment

Comment: I cannot see any obvious problems, so I must suspect there's a race condition.

Comment: We cannot see any obvious problems either because you have not supplied the data structs or the calling code. How can we tell if your pay pointer is valid? We surely cannot tell if your design is thread/interrupt safe.

Comment: updating my question. wait

Comment: **Everything in this code is wrong.** We do not see the declarations of ethernet, ip or tcp header but there is no guarantee that you can add the 14 bytes of sizeof ethernet header and land to a location that is aligned properly for an IP header.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala check my update of question

Comment: this this its related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905392/passing-char-uninitialiezed-pointer-address-and-allocation-and-extraction-of-mem

Comment: Ok the problem is that you're **not** introducing another variable. Do not try to "conserve" memory, make another variable of type `char *` to use within that function and you can get rid of those silly `*`  everywhere.

Comment: What is this `t1` nonsense? Why you have some random `sizeof (int)` to add to the malloc? None of this makes sense.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905392/passing-char-uninitialiezed-pointer-address-and-allocation-and-extraction-of-mem

Comment: I did see it, hence my comments there. What I said above does not contradict what Dude said there. Your code does not constitute a [mre], it is just some dump into the question box. It is very easy to tell because you didn't even care to strip out commented code!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853263/creating-my-own-struct-for-a-packet-that-need-to-be-sent-from-a-server-to-a-clie?noredirect=1#comment118176676_66853263

Comment: printfs inside a lock:((

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what I found is that in `memcpy` the destination is  `NULL` but the struct which contains destination is NOT `NULL` so basically `struct packets` is not NULL but gdb `print` printing 0 for         `unsigned char   h_dest[ETH_ALEN];/*destination eth addr */`

Comment: @MartinJames `We cannot see any obvious problems either because you have not supplied the data structs or the calling code. How can we tell if your pay pointer is valid?` please look at the `update 2` of this question and my last comment

Comment: question updated with `struct` and debug info

Comment: @WeatherVane I have updated my question with debug info and `struct packet definition` char *pay` is also defined in calling function. I think that's enough info and two ppl have also voted to down-close the question. Can u please look at it. At least add what else do u need me to do with `gdb` to down-close.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala full code of the program. Please look at this. to all as well who asked for code https://github.com/fawadfwd/PacketMMAP_Server

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @dbush is it better than gdb?

Comment: @666 It's a different tool.  It tells you if you write outside memory bounds, dereference invalid pointers, or leak memory.  Give it a try.

Comment: @dbush ok will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You report that given this setup ...

> ```
>     void get_payload_to_send(struct packets *p,char **pay)
>     {
>         printf("%s --->>> %s",p->ip_source,p->ip_dest);
>         int t1;
>         *pay=(char *) malloc(sizeof(t1)+1020/*1000=payload*/);
>         memset (*pay, 0, sizeof(t1)+1020);
>         struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *pay;
>         struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
>         struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
> ```

... you find that this `memcpy()` throws a segfault:

> ```
> memcpy(eth->h_dest,p->h_source,sizeof(eth->h_source));
> ```

, with gdb revealing to you that `eth->h_dest` is null at the time of the call.

Well, the destination pointer being null completely explains the segfault.  And if `eth->h_dest` is a pointer and all-bits-zero is a null pointer representation for its type, then **of course** it is null.  You set it to all-bits zero with your `memset()` call.

You need either to allocate sufficient (additional) space for `eth->h_dest` to point to before copying data there, or else use pointer assignment to point it to an existing object.  The context is not sufficiently clear for me to judge which of those would be more appropriate.

Comment: After the post I did exactly this what u said  `else use pointer assignment to point it to an existing object` this thing was fixed some time ago. But it was very important for me to this ur info. Thanks for this. Can u please look at this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042985/whats-the-point-of-dma-proxy-or-can-we-use-kernel-data-structures-in-userspace

Comment: can you please tell little about `copying ethernet frames to user buffer` this is the question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054910/question-about-dma-proxy-on-how-its-used-to-copy-ethernet-frames-to-user-buffer. btw thank you very much for answering the question in above link. I have totally accepted the answer, thanks again.

Comment: If u know any kernel programming please look at the above comment link. Let me know if u need any changes to the question. I kind of stuck for last 2 days just a comment may be. I got no replies still.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mayor errors on these lines:

```
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *pay;
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

- Memory pointed by `pay*` was allocated using a magic number, the size of `ethhdr`, `iphdr` and `tcphdr` might be the same, but I wouldn't like to work on that code, accesses out of boundaries are likely.
- Regarding alignment, it may happen that `ethhdr` has to land on an multiple of X, but `pay` is not. That will trigger an error (`malloc` will return an address whose alignment is at least [max_align_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t), but everything may happen with the extra additions).

Comment: There is no strict aliasing violation in the lines quoted, nor do they appear to be creating a situation that would facilitate such an issue later.  The pointed-to memory has no effective type until it is written to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have updated my answer to clarify why I do think there is a strict aliasing problem.

Comment: Regarding alignment, I think we are saying the same, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Read the SAR in the context of [its preceding paragraph](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7), and pay particular attention to the careful use of the term "effective type" in the SAR itself (paragraph 6.5/8).  If you still think you see SAR violations, then the explanation in this answer should be augmented with what you think the effective types of the objects involved are, and what the types of the lvalues being used to access them are.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right, I was 100% sure that memset would change the effective type, but it doesn't. Thanks for your time and the reference.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are not supplying the correct pointer to `memset()`:

```c
char *pay=(char *) malloc(sizeof(t1)+1020);
memset (*pay, 0, sizeof(t1)+1020);
```

clears memory using the first `char` in the dynamically allocated array `pay` as the target address.

The correct form is

```c
char *pay = malloc(sizeof(t1)+1020);
memset (pay, 0, sizeof(t1)+1020);
```

This is because `pay` is the pointer that refers to the dynamically allocated array, whereas `*pay` refers to the value of its first element just like `pay[0]`.

(In C, the explicit cast from void *, such as the return value from malloc(), is not needed.)

---

The same error is duplicated several times:

```c
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *pay;
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

These declare and initialize pointers to addresses derived from the first char in the dynamically allocated array `pay`, rather than addresses relative to the beginning of the array.

Again, their correct form is

```c
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) pay;
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (pay + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

because `*pay` refers to the value of the first element in the `pay` array, whereas `pay` refers to the address of the array.

---

Apparently, the actual code is

```c
char **pay;

*pay = malloc(sizeof (t1) + 1020);
memset (*pay, 0, sizeof (t1) + 1020);
```

This lacks two essential checks:

1. That `pay` is not NULL
2. That `malloc()` succeeded

The code can fail for either reason with the symptoms described.  At **minimum**, rewrite this as

```c
assert(pay != NULL);
*pay = malloc(sizeof (t1) + 1020);
assert(*pay != NULL);
memset(*pay, 0, sizeof (t1) + 1020);
```

with the `eth`, `ip`, and `tcp` variable definitions kept in their original form (i.e., with `*pay`).

Comment: Now exception is getting thrown at this line `ip->daddr=s2.sin_addr.s_addr;` inside `get_payload_to_send` function in thread two. GDB says `ip` is `0xe` but when I try to print `ip->daddr` gdb says `Cannot access memory at address 0x1e`

Comment: @666: You have the same error consistently in your code.  You use the value of the first element of the `pay` array, `*pay`, when you should use the address of the array, `pay`.

Comment: @Glärbo `pay` has type `char **`, so none of this applies.

Comment: @Glärbo  The line in the function is `*pay=(char *) malloc(sizeof(t1)+1020/*1000=payload*/);`.  The function's signature is `void get_payload_to_send(struct packets *p,char **pay)`.  So `*pay` is a `char *` that holds the address returned by `malloc`.