# DMA proxy and how it is used to copy ethernet frames to user buffer

Tags: c, dma

This is the code I am refering to: https://github.com/mstuehn/dma_proxy/blob/master/dma_proxy.c

At line `841` it uses call to `dma_set_coherent_mask` and passing generic device `pchannel_p->proxy_device_p`.

```
    dma_set_coherent_mask(pchannel_p->proxy_device_p, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            pchannel_p->interface_p = (struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *)
                dmam_alloc_coherent(pchannel_p->proxy_device_p,
                                    sizeof(struct dma_proxy_channel_interface),
                                    &pchannel_p->interface_phys_addr, GFP_KERNEL);
```

`pchannel_p` is of type `dma_proxy_channel`.

```
    struct dma_proxy_channel {
        struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *interface_p;    /* user to kernel space interface */
        dma_addr_t interface_phys_addr;

        struct device *proxy_device_p;              /* character device support */
        struct device *dma_device_p;
        dev_t dev_node;
        struct cdev cdev;
        struct class *class_p;

        struct dma_chan *channel_p;             /* dma support */
        struct completion cmp;
        dma_cookie_t cookie;
        dma_addr_t dma_handle;
        u32 direction;                      /* DMA_MEM_TO_DEV or DMA_DEV_TO_MEM */
    };
```

`static struct dma_proxy_channel channels[CHANNEL_COUNT];`

This is how its passed to `create_channel` where multiple calls to `dma_set_coherent_mask` are made for both `_rx` and `_tx`.

`create_channel(&channels[0], "_tx", DMA_MEM_TO_DEV);`

My question is: if my device -- that the DMA proxy driver targets -- is a PCI network card (NIC card) then will I supply `struct pci_dev obj_rx` and `struct pci_dev_tx` to two calls to `dma_set_coherent_mask` to create DMA channels for both receive and transmit?

And if I want to be able to read network packets then how is it possible since I see using NAPI and `ISR` will look bit odd since my char driver will not be able to read `ethernet` frames and copy them to user buffer since that work needed to be done in read or mmap.

So how can I suppose to read a packet from userspace application with `mmap` or `read` system calls? What do I have to add to copy `ethernet` frames to user buffer and be able to get packets with application's `mmap` and `read` calls?

**update**

I just want some one to read the comment link I posted. And give me some close semblence of working solution for rx and tx. For any device. I will use Realteck r 8169 device. Kernel has its sources as driver.

Comment: Perfect still no comments or anything. Sometimes I just got this feeling there has to be some forum for learning kernel developers.

Comment: This question seems extremely specific to your particular, fairly unusual, situation.  Sometimes we can address such questions, but other times not.  Your chances would be better, though, if you swapped out one of your current tags for the "C" tag.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for your comment. all this time I was just adding these tags in my questions and kept waiting any response. thanks again I just did exactly this

Comment: Have you read this guide -> https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/core-api/dma-api-howto.html ?

Comment: I suggested swapping out *one* of the tags, not replacing *all* of them with just the C tag.  It is helpful to have a language tag on your questions, as the language tags tend to have many more watchers than others, but we still like to see additional tags to provide context where appropriate. And sometimes these will draw respondents who otherwise would miss it.

Comment: I have already told you yo read the documentation. Try to make your question a bit lees of a mess. For instance, `dma_set_coherent_mask()` has nothing to do with **requesting** (creating in your terms I guess) channels. On top of that you need to read some books about computer hardware (also I had told this), to understand, in particular, what’s DMA and how it works on a signal level.

Comment: @0andriy can u direct me some book about dma proxy. All I could find is dma engine api like https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/9781785280009/26250ed8-a263-4910-8d43-5c6e1a6d753f.xhtml  I just want to be able to do tx/rx from application to/from dma proxy to/from device.

Comment: Please see my last comment

Comment: Do you have hardware that allows you to do so?

Comment: @0andriy its nic card. Supports dma

Comment: So what I found using so is it's simply for javascript and css.